# Google Admin SDK API for Mail Log Query

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-admin-audit-api

Does anyone know if the google Admin SDK API has functionality for querying it's E-Mail log search?

The functionality I'm referring to is found [1].
From the reading, It appears to be only available via the Admin Console and I was able to find any reference to it in the API docs.

If such is not available, does anyone know off the top of their heads, whether or not writing a screenscaper/bot to do these queries independent of an API would violate TOS?

References:
1. https://support.google.com/a/answer/2604578?hl=en

Comment: You can check the solution of this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074992/service-worker-network-first-then-cache-with-fallback-to-static-page). I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: I am sorry Jess, perhaps, I'm missing something but I don't see how the referenced SO post is related to the question about Google Admin SDK having the ability to query the mail logs.

Answer (score 1):

To your first question: There is not currently a way to get the email logs via the API. [People have been looking for it for some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040937/google-email-log-search-api).