# getting active user name in Google sheets from external domain

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I have a published web app:

```
function doGet(request) {
   // DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var about = Drive.About.get();
  var user = about.name;
  // Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
   return ContentService.createTextOutput(user);
}
```

... at this URL:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzTlhKJXrTAEPEba0l1KWqqzlkul2ntC-0iHi7_POj0wk7j3R6K/exec

Which produces the desired result the user's full name (after authorization to user's data is approved - subsequent running of the URL does not prompt for authentication or approval)

*That* is the data I want to retrieve from this App Script:

```
function Test3() {
  var options = {
    'method' : 'get', 
    'followRedirects' : true,
    // 'validateHttpsCertificates' : 'true',
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
    'contentType' : 'null'
  };

 var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzTlhKJXrTAEPEba0l1KWqqzlkul2ntC-0iHi7_POj0wk7j3R6K/exec"

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  // var response = test2() ;
  // var myName = response.getContentText();
  Browser.msgBox("[" + response + "]");
  }
```

but I have not been able to get just that data. Instead I get an a page HTML text, which equates to a Google login page.

Again, just running the URL manually from a browser as any user results in the user name web page, so why when run from app script, it can't just retrieve the result of that page?

What am I missing?  Surely I'm some simple syntax away from getting that data.

Comment: If you're looking for a related code, you can probably check this SO post - [Service worker - network first then cache with fallback to static page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074992/service-worker-network-first-then-cache-with-fallback-to-static-page). Here's also a guide for [Service Worker](https://love2dev.com/blog/service-worker-cache/) for more info.

Comment: I don't see how that helps with my problem/question. This sounds like it will allow me to retrieved cache information, but I can't get the response in the cache in the first place.